# Set range as a single cell relative to active cell

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset

When I try and define a range as a single cell relative to the current cell, I get an error that the range failed:

```
If target.Cells.Column = 2 Then
    If target.Cells.Row > 3 Then
        If target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Select
        End If
    End If
End If
```

I know I could create the range at the current cell and then offset afterwards but I just want to define the range

Comment: You aren't defining a range in your code, your Selecting one. What is Target? Is this inside a WorkSheet_Change or WorkSheet_SelectionChange event?

Comment: Can you explain the outcome that you want from this please. At the moment you are selecting a cell, but then not doing anything with it. Is your aim to return a range variable, return a string variable representing the address or do something else?

Comment: The `Range` argument either needs to be entered as text or a second reference supplied for the code to compile. In this case it is redundant anyway as you can just use: `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim c As Range

If target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If target.Row > 3 and target.Column = 2 Then
        Set c = target.Offset(0, 1)
        'do something with c
    End If
End If
```